# After editing the table cell value clicking on next or previous button, I get the non modified table

Tags: python

I am trying to make a dash app  where there is a list of image when I click on next button the image will move forward and there is a table which will change accordingly and if I click on previous button this will perform vice versa. my problem is that if change any value of the cell in this table and while clicking the next button or previous button ; after that I came again  I get the non modified table. I want to keep the modified table whenever I go to next or previous.

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc, Input, Output, State, dash_table
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
    meta_tags=[
        {"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"}
    ],
)

image_list = [
    "assets/images.jpeg",
    "assets/download.jpeg",
    "assets/images (1).jpeg",
    "assets/dx.png",
    "assets/imagesd1.jpeg",
    "assets/images2.jpeg"
]

data = {
    'A': [2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22],
    'B': [3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23],
    'C': [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24],
    'D': [5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25]
}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
table_data = [{'Feature': col, 'Value': data[col][0]} for col in data.columns]

image_index = 0

edited_values = {}  # Store edited cell values

row_1 = dbc.Row(
    [
        dbc.Col(
            [
                html.H5('OCR Validator', style={"text-align": "center"}),
            ]
        )
    ],
    style={'backgroundColor': 'lightblue'}
)

row_2 = dbc.Row(
    [
        dbc.Col(
            [
                dbc.Row(
                    [
                        dbc.Col(
                            [
                                html.Br(),
                                html.Div(id="empty-div"),
                                html.Img(
                                    id='image',
                                    src=image_list[0],
                                    style={
                                        'width': '400px',
                                        'height': '500px',
                                        'margin-left': '100px',
                                        'margin-top': '30px',
                                        'margin-bottom': '40px',
                                        'margin-right': '150px'
                                    }
                                ),
                                dbc.Row(
                                    [
                                        dbc.Col(
                                            [
                                                dbc.Button(
                                                    "Previous",
                                                    id="previous-button",
                                                    color="primary"
                                                ),
                                            ],
                                        ),
                                        dbc.Col(
                                            [
                                                dbc.Button(
                                                    "Next",
                                                    id="next-button",
                                                    color="primary",
                                                    style={'margin-left': '197px', 'width': '90px'}
                                                ),
                                            ],
                                            style={'backgroundColor': 'gray'}
                                        )
                                    ],
                                    style={'backgroundColor': 'gray', 'border-radius': '5px'}
                                )
                            ],
                            width=12,
                            style={
                                'border-width': '25px',
                                'backgroundColor': 'White',
                                'border-radius': '10px',
                                'border': '2px solid black',
                                'margin-right': 0,
                                'height': 700
                            }
                        )
                    ],
                    style={
                        'height': 700,
                        'margin-left': '0px',
                        'margin-right': '10px',
                        'margin-top': '0px',
                        'backgroundColor': 'skyblue'
                    }
                )
            ],
            width=6,
            style={'backgroundColor': '#FAF9F6'}
        ),
        dbc.Col(
            [
                html.Br(),
                html.Br(),
                html.Br(),
                html.H3('Table Section'),
                html.Hr(),
                html.Br(),
                
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    id='table',
                    columns=[{'name': 'Feature', 'id': 'Feature'}, {'name': 'Value', 'id': 'Value'}],
                    data=table_data,
                    page_action='none',
                    fixed_rows={'headers': True},
                    editable=True,
                    style_table={'width': '500px', 'height': '180px', 'margin-left': 30},
                    #page_size=4,
                    style_cell={
                        'textAlign': 'center',
                        'padding': '0px',
                        'minWidth': 90,
                        'maxWidth': 90,
                        'width': 90,
                        'overflow': 'hidden',
                        'height': 'auto',
                        'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
                        'font-family': 'monospace',
                        'transform': 'rotate(-360deg)'
                    },
                
                ),
                html.Br(),
                html.Button('Save Table', id='save-table-button', n_clicks=0),
                dbc.Alert(
                    "Table data saved!",
                    id="confirmation-message",
                    color="success",
                    dismissable=True,
                    is_open=False,
                )
            ],
            style={
                'backgroundColor': '#fffdd0',
                'border': '2px solid black',
                'border-radius': '15px',
                'margin-right': '13px'
            }
        )
    ],
    style={'height': '700px', 'backgroundColor': 'white'}
)

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        row_1,
        row_2,
    ],
    fluid=False,
    style={'border': '3px solid black'}
)


@app.callback(
    Output('table', 'data'),
    Output('image', 'src'),
    Input('next-button', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('previous-button', 'n_clicks'),
    State('table', 'data')
)
def update_table_and_image(next_clicks, previous_clicks, table_data):
    global image_index

    ctx = dash.callback_context
    button_id = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]

    if button_id == 'next-button':
        image_index = (image_index + 1) % len(image_list)
    elif button_id == 'previous-button':
        image_index = (image_index - 1) % len(image_list)

    next_image = image_list[image_index]
    table_data = [{'Feature': col, 'Value': edited_values.get(col, data[col][image_index])} for col in data.columns]

    return table_data, next_image


@app.callback(
    Output('empty-div', 'children'),
    Input('table', 'data_previous'),
    State('table', 'data')  # Get the current table data
)
def handle_table_edits(previous_data,current_data):
    global edited_values
    
    if previous_data != current_data:
        for row in current_data:
            feature = row['Feature']
            edited_values[feature] = row['Value']

    return html.H1("")
   

@app.callback(
    Output("confirmation-message", "is_open"),
    Output("save-table-button", "n_clicks"),
    Input("save-table-button", "n_clicks"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def display_confirmation_message(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        return True, 0
    return False, 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I am facing a python dash related problem and hope I can get the solution from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g706S.png)